# How do i do IP address translation with iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat

I need to create a route in iptables which allows to use my second IP address as source(not default one) when i connect to an external FTP server. How do i create that route for iptables? i am not very familiar with Linux/Redhat any help on the commands would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a source NATing rule like:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s your_private_ip -d FTP_server_ip -j SNAT --to-source your_public_ip
```

You can also specify the interface using `-i eth0`.

Comment: Thanks aflot  for the tips. May i know, -i eth0 is another way to do it ?. By the way, how can i bind the secondary IP address to the server ? i have 5 available IP addresses in the rance, how can i bind one to the server as secondary IP to use it in the route ?

Comment: @taras: I mean you can restrict the rule to be applied on specific interface only if required. You can bind another IP using the command: `ifconfig eth0:0 your_ip netmask your_mask`.

Comment: just wanted to check, in your code: -s your_private_ip is it default public IP or default local IP ? thanks for comments, i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @taras: You can specify the matched source IP address using `-s your_private_ip`. So, this will match the traffic sent from this IP. Similarly, using `-d FTP_server_ip` will restrict the match further to the packets destined to the FTP server.

Comment: i got this error: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: for -s your_private_ip i set my primary IP address(default)

Comment: @taras: Sorry I forgot to add the table name. You need to specify the table using `-t nat` as shown in the answer above.

Comment: yeah, thanks alot! it worked, need to restart iptables now? how can i check that the route is working now ? coz the IP is not enabled yet in the external FTP server firewall yet, is there any way to make sure that the route works ?

Comment: @taras: You can list the rules and their counters (hits) using the command: `iptables -L -n -v -x`. There is no restart for iptables! If you are typing the command on the terminal, there is nothing to do.

Comment: i see, but for this iptables -L -n -v -x i can see it only after some connection established ? is there any way to check it in advance ? or to see all iptable routes ?